# Counting the independent sets of a comparability graph with maximum degree 3. Is it #P−complete ?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

This question was first asked here:
[cstheory.stackexchange...](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/7710/counting-the-independent-sets-of-a-comparability-graph-with-maximum-degree-3-is)

Here we want to count the number of independent sets of a comparability graph. For Δ(G)=2 , i.e. the maximum degree of a vertex in G  is 2, the number of independent sets can be found in linear time. For Δ(G)=4 , the problem is very hard (#P-complete  ?). Take for example the grid graph.

I am wondering about the case of Δ(G)=3 . It seems that it is very simple.

Thank you for your advice/comments in advance. :-)